# Mathematica equivalent to Python long raw strings? handling escape characters in packages

Tags: string-manipulation, input-forms

I'd like to write the following in plain text .m file in Mathematica, without having to double escape all the Latex commands:

```
s = ToString["\\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\\begin{document}
It is known that $\\sin(0)=" <> ToString[Sin[0]] <> "$
\\end{document}"];
```

Is there a way to do the above?

reference: [How do I make a string literal without having to escape backslashes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76647/how-do-i-make-a-string-literal-without-having-to-escape-backslashes)

Comment: @Pickett How to type the solution in plain text? as in .m file? I tried `TextCell` but not sure I am doing it correctly. Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KPdm1.png) I do not know how to do the ctrl-9 and ctrl-0 stuff in text file. I use plain text .m files. If you can show how to do it, using my example above, without using notebook interface, just using plain text input, then that will help

Comment: @Nasser I don't believe you can do that. The `InputForm` of Jens' solution is `TextCell["\\abc\\def\\ghi"]`.

Comment: @Pickett, I am confused. So what should I type for my example above?  In the .m file? I do not want to put "\\" in there.  I still do not know what the syntax I am supposed to use.

Comment: As far as I know the syntax you are seeking does not exist.  I guess since the Accepted method there is unworkable for you this question may not be a duplicate, but IMHO you should reference that question and simplify your own, then note specifically that you want entry from within a Package.

Comment: @Nasser Have you considered using XML templates?

Comment: @Pickett, no I do not want to get into XML and all that. way to complicated. I simply want to use Mathematica and generate Latex from it without having to keep typing "\\" all time.

Comment: @Nasser OK, it's just a suggestion. I retracted my close vote in response to your update.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your situation. You write an .m file with WL code in it. Then what? If you run it from the command line it should be straightforward to write a shell script that preprocesses the file and adds the escape \ for you before it passes the file to the kernel.

Comment: @Pickett  I run the .m file using Mathematica, but from command line, not from the notebook.  it is an .m file. How will I write a script that look into huge .m file of Mathematica code, prarses it, looks for certain places with strings, and replace each "\" with "\\"? Also there are things like "\n" in there, which should be left alone. It is not that easy to do. I also have to do this each time I edit the .m file again. Way too complicated. Python solution is much simpler actually. I just write `r"""....."""` and that is it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had another answer to this question (now located [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86910/8253)) that used the global variable `$PreRead` to convert raw strings to `InputForm` prior to evaluation. Unfortunately, that method only works when evaluating the package file interactively, as you would a notebook file. It does not work when loading a package with `Get`, because `$PreRead` is not applied to the expressions that are read in from the package file before they are evaluated.

On the other hand, if we are just interested in using raw strings in package files that are to be read in, we can easily preprocess the package files to replace raw strings as they are being read.

One method (possibly not for the faint of heart) is to overload `Get` for designated package files. Suppose we want to implement the Python raw string syntax for any package file whose name ends with `_raw.m`. In your `init.m` file, place the following code:

```
Unprotect[Get];

Get[file_String] /; StringMatchQ[file, "*_raw.m"] && FileType[file] === File :=
  ToExpression@StringReplace[
    Import[file, "Text"], 
    "r\"\"\"" ~~ Shortest[str__] ~~ "\"\"\"" :> ToString@InputForm@str
]

Protect[Get];
```

Now make a test package file `test_raw.m` with contents

```
s = r"""\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
It is known that $\sin(0)=""" <> ToString[Sin[0]] <> r"""$
\end{document}"""

Print[s]
```

Now, at the command line,

```
$ math -script test_raw.m
```

returns

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
It is known that $\sin(0)=0$
\end{document}
```

It also works when using `Get["test_raw.m"]` or `<< test_raw.m`. The "context" form `` <<test_raw` `` doesn't work; to get it to work we'd have to sacrifice the underscore in the file name, which isn't allowed in a context specifier. Then we'd want to lengthen the designator suffix, maybe to `rawstring.m`, to reduce the chance of other package files accidentally matching the pattern.

Comment: Very nice! It works very well so far. I also wrote the string to Latex file, and it compiled with pdflatex with no problems. I tested it on this file `SetDirectory["G:\\tmp"];
Print[Directory[]]

s=r"""\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
  \begin{document}
  \title{title}
  \date{1/1/2015}
  
  The following in known equation $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ and this
  is 100% correct. This was written on 1/1/2015 and this is a
  string "I am a string" and this is \\n which is left as is.
 \end{document}""";
 
 Print[s]
 str = OpenWrite["foo.tex"];
 WriteString[str,s];
 Close[str]
 ` thanks.

Comment: I've been testing it, and so far I see no issues. It also handles embedded strings and everything else like Python's `r"""`.

Comment: @Nasser Great. Let me know if you find any issues with it.

Comment: Would you happen to know why this method does not work when using the syntax `math.exe < foo.m` and one must use `math.exe -script foo.m` ? The reason I am asking is that using the first syntax above allows one to see the commands (IN and OUT) on the screen as they are evaluated as discussed in this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79254/how-to-send-out-output-to-stdout-when-running-a-script-from-command-line-on-wido) which makes it easier to see where the error is. Would be hard to modify your method to make it work with the first case as well? thanks

Comment: @Nasser It works with `math.exe -script foo.m` because in script mode the kernel reads the whole input file at once using `Get`. The syntax `math.exe < foo.m` is the same as interactive mode, but with input being read in (presumably one line at a time) from `foo.m` instead of from `stdin`. If we could find what Mma function is being used to read in the input, we could probably adapt this solution to work, but I haven't been able to yet. Another possibility would be to process the input file with another script and then feed it to the kernel, but so far I haven't found an easy way to do that.

Comment: No problem Simon. Everything is working very well. Except that when an problem happen, hard to know from which line it came, since I do not see the commands as they run. But I am using lots of `Print` in the script to help :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, an approach like this may work for you:

```
clean = {
   "\t" -> "\\t",
   "\b" -> "\\b",
   "\n" -> "\\n"};

StringReplace["\begin{5}", clean]
```

If too many exceptions appear it may be easier to set up something with FromCharacterCode.

---

Interesting, I found that `InputForm` auto-strings its argument, like a string version of `Hold`:

```
In[1]:= InputForm["\t"]

Out[1]//InputForm= "\t"

In[2]:= InputForm["\t"] // ToString // Characters

Out[2]= {"\"", "\\", "t", "\""}
```

So maybe just this will work for you:

```
r = StringTrim[ToString[InputForm[#]], "\""] &;

r@"\t"
```

That this works through the function seems to imply certain things about where escape sequences are processed.

Comment: The `InputForm` trick seems to work, even though it produces warnings about "Unknown string escape" characters if I try it with the example in the question. I guess one can just ignore those warnings.

Comment: I was working on this approach, but gave up, since I don't think it's feasible. A major issue is that any line breaks in the original string are converted to `\\n` in the output, which is not what's desired. Try it with the example string from the OP. Also, a backslash followed by a space is a commonly used LaTeX command, but Mathematica automatically converts `"\ "` to `" "` before anything can be done with it.

Comment: If you do want to try this method, you can use `Off[Syntax::stresc]` to get get rid of the warnings. Also, you'll want to extend the list of replacements to `{"\b" -> "\\b", "\f" -> "\\f", "\n" -> "\\n", "\r" -> "\\r", "\t" -> "\\t"}`.

Comment: @SimonRochester Strange, in my test the line break was correctly appearing as `\n`. So I think this is still closer to the goal than my approach. **But** after looking more closely, I don't think it's completely reliable after all.

Comment: @Jens If you just use `// InputForm // ToString` then the line breaks are fine. But then, for example, you won't convert the LaTeX command `"\nu"` properly to `"\\nu"`. So you need to add a `StringReplace` with `"\n" -> "\\n"`, at which point I think the line breaks will be messed up...

Comment: @SimonRochester I agree - I already upvoted, but it's not perfect...

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent to Python's `r`. So from the comments it's clear that we have to *cheat* in order to get this formatting to work purely in a text file environment. One obvious way to do it is as follows:

```
toString[x_]:=StringReplace[x,""->"\\"];
s = toString["documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}                                               
begin{document}                                                                                    
It is known that $sin(0)=" <> ToString[Sin[0]] <> "$                                               
end{document}"];
Export["snippet.tex",s,"Text"]
```

Here, I simply decided to replace the special character `\` in the $\LaTeX$ code ("special" because it has catcode `0` in $\TeX$ and at the same time is used in newlines etc., which makes it hard to isolate in a string replacement) by a less special character that is never used for anything else, either in normal text or in `$\TeX$`. In the example, I chose ``, but you could for example also choose `>` or `<`, if you use standard $\LaTeX$ (because then you'll type `\leq` etc. instead of these symbols; of course, that would then become `<leq`).

The point of this exercise is that the single replacement character (such as ``) is reasonably easy to type (I have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> to get that symbol) and equally easy to recognize as the prefix of a $\LaTeX$ command, compared to the original `\`. But now we can easily use `StringReplace` to do the ugly replacement by `\\` behind the scenes. If you do it this way, you can choose any replacement character that is not already assigned a meaning either as a letter or a special catcode allowed to appear in $\LaTeX$.