# A pre-parsed HoldForm

Tags: programming, evaluation

`HoldForm` holds an expression's *parsed* form not its actual "inputted form" e.g.

```
 SetAttributes[AttemptedRespect, HoldAll];
 AttemptedRespect[x_] := ExpressionCell[HoldForm@x, "Input"]

(assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>) // AttemptedRespect
```

> `assoc = Association[f[x] -> g[x]]`

where the held short forms/notation of `Association`/`f`/`g` are no longer respected.

To instigate respect:

```
 FleetingRespect[expr_] :=
 (Unprotect@Association;
 Format[Association[x__]] := <|x|>;
 Format[f[x_]] := Prefix[f@x];
 Format[g[x_]] := Postfix[x // g];
 ExpressionCell[HoldForm@expr, "Input"])
```

and:

```
(assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>) // FleetingRespect
```

> `assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>`

which is, of course, indeed fleeting:

```
(assoc = Association[(x // f) -> (g@x)]) // FleetingRespect
```

> `assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>`

Is there a way to cajole `HoldForm` into more faithfully respecting what she wraps?

In other words - a function `PermanentRespect` such that:

```
(assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>) // PermanentRespect
```

> `assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>`

and

```
(assoc = Association[(x // f) -> (g@x)]) // PermanentRespect
```

> `assoc = Association[(x // f) -> (g@x)]`

Yoh - Respect.

**Answer:** The final effort in Simon Rochester's answer *almost* creates a pre-parsed `HoldForm` (without touching `$PreRead`) and it certainly meets the use-case requirements that originally motivated the question. Essentially I wanted to programmatically generate the "natural input shortforms" with normal output form (without using any frontend manipulations).

```
MakeExpression[
   RowBox@{"hf", "[", expr_, "]"} | 
   RowBox@{"hf", "@", expr_} | 
   RowBox@{expr_, "//", "hf"}, StandardForm] := HoldComplete@RawBoxes@expr;

SetAttributes[IOCells, HoldAll];

IOCells[expr_] := Grid[{
    {ExpressionCell[expr, "Input", ShowStringCharacters -> True]},         
    {ExpressionCell[ToExpression@First@expr, "Output"]}}, 
          Frame -> True,
          Alignment -> Left,
          Background -> {None, {1 -> GrayLevel[.9], 2 -> White}}];
```

and now both examples

```
Grid[{
   {hf[assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>],
    hf[assoc = Association[(x // f) -> (g@x)]]}
      }] // (Map[IOCells, #, {3}] &)
```

[image]

preserve input forms, respectively.

Comment: `PermanentRespect` should also not have lingering side affects. e.g.  `FleetingRespect` pollutes the name space while ensuring that `Association` formats with <|  |> has unexpected consequences (e.g. `AssociationMap[f]@<|a->1|>` goes into infinite recursion )

Comment: Because this relates to parsing, the use of `PreRead`, `RawBoxes` etc seems unavoidable although in this use case this seems disproportionate, unjustified spelunking. Functions like `Inactivate`/`Activate` perhaps suggest new attention to formatting of Input forms which made me wonder if a `PermanentRespect` is implementable at a higher level.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(83698)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83698/121).  Also related (Stack Overflow): [(12598697)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12598697/618728)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `$PreRead` may be your only hope (but see below). You can set it up with

```
$PreRead = (# /. 
  RowBox@{"PermanentRespect", "[", expr_, "]"} | 
  RowBox@{"PermanentRespect", "@", expr_} | 
  RowBox@{expr_, "//", "PermanentRespect"} :> 
    RowBox@{"RawBoxes", "[", MakeBoxes@expr, "]"}
) &;

LoseRespect[expr_] := expr /. RawBoxes -> ToExpression
```

Now you can do

```
(assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>) // PermanentRespect
```

> `(assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>)`

or

```
expr = PermanentRespect[(assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>)]
```

> `(assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>)`

The expression hasn't been evaluated:

```
assoc
```

> `assoc`

Evaluate it with `LoseRespect`:

```
LoseRespect[expr]
```

> `<|f[x] -> g[x]|>`

---

Despite what I said above, I think `$PreRead` may not be your only hope. Here's another solution that uses `NotebookRead` to get the box representation of the currently evaluating cell. It then looks through those boxes to find the box representation of the call to itself, and returns that wrapped in `RawBoxes`.

(First clear `$PreRead` with `$PreRead =.` if the definition above is still active.)

Define `PermanentRespect`:

```
SetAttributes[PermanentRespect, HoldAll]

PermanentRespect[expr_] := 
  First@Cases[
    NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]], 
    RowBox@{"PermanentRespect", "[", boxes_, "]"} | 
      RowBox@{"PermanentRespect", "@", boxes_} | 
      RowBox@{boxes_, "//", "PermanentRespect"} /; 
      MakeExpression[boxes, StandardForm] == HoldComplete[expr] :> RawBoxes[boxes], 
    Infinity
  ]
```

Now `PermanentRespect` gives the same results as obtained above.

---

I'm getting more wrong by the minute about `$PreRead` -- here's a third solution that employs a custom definition for `MakeExpression`, which is used whenever boxes are converted to expressions by the front end:

```
ClearAll[PermanentRespect]

MakeExpression[
  RowBox@{"PermanentRespect", "[", expr_, "]"} | 
    RowBox@{"PermanentRespect", "@", expr_} | 
    RowBox@{expr_, "//", "PermanentRespect"}, 
  StandardForm
] := HoldComplete@RawBoxes@expr
```

This also gives the same results as above.

---

Also, any of the above methods can be used with `.m` package files, if the package file is evaluated as a notebook instead of using `Get`. You can define

```
myGet[file_] := Module[{obj},
  obj = NotebookOpen[file, Visible -> False];
  NotebookEvaluate[obj];
  NotebookClose[obj]
]
```

Then if the package file is loaded with `myGet["package.m"]`, the `PermanentRespect` function calls inside the package will behave as above.

Comment: Yes, you might be right.  I do get nervous though about tinkering with `$PreRead` (even if your succinct solution does seem watertight). In particular, I kind of wanted to avoid its use as it seems like bad form to potentially distribute a notebook with `$PreRead` altered (since things are no longer isolated as with packages). Your solution could still be useful though in the use-case of just demonstrating user-input since this could be pre-generated prior to distribution (i.e. `$PreRead` changed during generation but not required from the users end - with the possible drawback ...

Comment: ... that with things not generated on the fly users receive a frozen-version's output [not an unimportant consideration given how fluid the Data Science functionality seems these days]). Unfortunately even this doesn't work with `$PreRead` in a package set-up since while the "input form" is preserved in a .m file when `assoc = <|f@x -> (x // g)|>` is placed in an initialization cell, reading this back in bypasses `$PreRead`'s setting (a condition I didn't mention in the question).

Comment: @RonaldMonson I agree that `$PreRead` is not ideal, for the reasons you cite. If you want to have this done in a package file, you may need to preprocess the package when loading it, somewhat along the lines of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86914/8253). It's likely to be much messier than that case, though.

Comment: @RonaldMonson On the other hand, I think I have another notebook-based solution that doesn't require `$PreRead`. I'll write it up.

Comment: Great. Looks workable. I will have a look at it tonight. B.T.W note that `"RawBoxes"` instead of `"DisplayForm"` seems to mean that `"LoseRespect"` is not necessary?

Comment: @RonaldMonson `RawBoxes` is nicer, because it's a little less obtrusive than `DisplayForm`. But I think you still need to replace `RawBoxes` with `ToExpression` if you want to evaluate the expression. Maybe I don't understand what exactly you want to do with these held expressions?

Comment: Good stuff. See answer for use-case. A full pre-parsed `HoldForm` is nearly there `MakeExpression[R : RowBox@{"HoldForm", "[", _, "]"} | RowBox@{"HoldForm", "@", _} | RowBox@{_, "//", "HoldForm"}, StandardForm] := HoldComplete@RawBoxes@R` returns the `HoldForm` output but in raw boxes. A final `ToExpression@First@` then completes the process but to do so in one hit, I suspect a `MakeBoxes` on each function form `[]`,`@`,`//` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem: You need to use literal (Verbatim) input lines from a notebook

After watching the one-liner competition, I decided just out of curiosity to create a function to count the number of characters of all input  expression in any notebook when I stumbled into the same problem:

```
In[1]:= StringLength[ToString[Unevaluated[Total@Range@5]]]

Out[1]:= 15
```

As you can see it should be 13 because that is the StringLength of the expression `Total@Range@5` when converted to a string. I tried setting the attributes of HoldAllComplete in a user defined function like so:

```
In[2]:= SetAttributes[charCount, HoldAllComplete]

In[3]:= charCount[Defer[expr_]]:= StringLength[ToString[Unevaluated[Total@Range@5]]]
```

But it did not work to force @ not to change to [ ].

### Solution:

I used NotebookGet and Cases with pattern matching to format the output.

```
codelineLength[notebookURL_String] := 
 Cases[NotebookGet[Import[notebookURL]], 
  Cell[t_, "Input", ___] :> DisplayForm@Cell[t], Infinity]
```

I added the following to make the literal input lines and their respective lengths easier to read at a glance.

```
Partition [
  Riffle[  StringLength[ToString[#]] & /@ 
    codelineLength["working.nb"], 
   codelineLength["working.nb"]], 2]  // TableForm
```

The following one produces a small table with the required information:

```
TableForm[ 
 MapIndexed[f, codelineLength["working.nb"]] /. 
  f[a_, b_] :> {First@b,  StringLength@ToString@a, a} , 
 TableSpacing -> 2, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"line number", "length", "literal input"}}, 
 TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image: Table]

I tried using `codelineLength` on an open notebook and it works well.